# Using wget to create a static mirror of a local WordPress installation

Tags: static-website

What is the established way of creating a static mirror of a local WordPress blog installation? (I'm managing it via wp-cli)

I've discovered https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-static/ but should `wget --mirror` also work and be enough to create a static html mirror of a simple WordPress blog installation along with all assets?

Is there a way to ask WordPress to bundle all plugins' assets (and maybe embed them into the page HTMLs)?

I'm looking into this as exploring transitioning of an existing WordPress blog to Static Site Generation. As an intermediate step, I'm looking to make WordPress itself into a SSG, basically populating the WordPress database, pages and config from some backup files and then render all the pages during the generation time. This would allow us to preserve the current website theme / design, while deciding if we move on to some other simpler SSG.

Thank you!

---

**UPD**: I've tried using sth like `wget -P wpssgmirror -nd --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites  --no-parent  --restrict-file-names=ascii,windows http://localhost:8080`, but it does not preserve the directory structure of the assets. It also has problems as it has `?ver=123` in the asset names